# How to solve exec format error while running container in ECS?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker

Previously the question was related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77266768/yarn-command-not-found-after-successful-docker-build. It was fixed but my problem is related to using shell `/bin/sh`.

Here's what I am trying to do: Use `yarn` and install it on `amazonlinux:2` image. Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2

RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install -y tar curl gzip zip unzip aws-cli

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.5/install.sh | sh && \
    . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && \
    nvm install 14 && \
    nvm alias default 14 && \
    nvm use default && \
    npm install -g yarn

USER root

COPY .bashrc /root/.bashrc

COPY entrypoint.sh /root/entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /root/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/root/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

And this is my `.bashrc` file

```
#!/bin/sh
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

ANd this is my `entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
. /root/.bashrc
exec "$@"
```

All I get is, while trying to run container from ECS,  `exec /root/entrypoint.sh: exec format error` and `Essential container in task exited`.

How to solve the exec format error?

Comment: Did you try simply switching to `/bin/bash`?